# (JAVA) having trouble counting the exact number of lines and other specific characters on files

Tags: java, file, io, bufferedreader

ok so i have two .txt files, one called "input.txt" and another called "output.txt". to create output i have to copy the text from input but replace all spaces between words with @'s and add a new line with the string "#NEW_LINE#" after each line of the original text

for example, if input.txt is this:

```
the unstoppable marching of time
that is slowly guiding us all towards
an inevitable death
```

then output.txt should be something like this:

```
the@unstoppable@marching@of@time
#NEW_LINE#
that@is@slowly@guiding@us@all@towards
#NEW_LINE#
an@inevitable@death 
#NEW_LINE#
```

anyway you get the idea.

now i dont have a problem with this particular task, but then i am also asked to print on the screen a message that shows the total number of lines of text from both files, and another that prints the total number of @'s from output.txt. and while i dont have trouble with counting the lines, their numbers show up correctly but i do have trouble figuring out the @'s... ill explain.

here's part of the code i tried at first: [btw this whole thing takes place on one class, with no other methods apart from main, of course. i thought it would be simpler that way idk ‍♂️]

```
  File fsrc=new File("input.txt");         
  File fdes=new File("output.txt");        


  int atCount = 0; //number of @'s
  int lineCountIN=0; //number of input's lines
  int lineCountOUT=0; //number of output's lines

  FileReader fr = new FileReader(fsrc);           
  BufferedReader br =new BufferedReader(fr);

  FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(fdes);
  String s = null;

  while((s=br.readLine())!=null)            
  {
     if ((s.equals(" "))) {
     fw.write(s.replace(" ","@"));
     atCount++; } 
     else fw.write(s);
     fw.write("\n");
     lineCountOUT++;
     lineCountIN++;
     fw.write("#NEW_LINE#");
     fw.write("\n");
     lineCountOUT++;
     fw.flush();  
  }  
  fw.close();
```

[...]

```
System.out.println("Total instances of @ characters at output.txt: " + atCount);
```

the message that pops up on the screen will always be: "Total instances of @ characters at output.txt:  0".

later i changed the if-else block to a do-while block:

```
do {
         fw.write(s.replace(" ","@"));
         atCount++; } 
     while ((s.equals(" ")));
```

but then the message does not return the exact number of @'s, in fact the number it shows just happens to be equal to lineCountIN for some reason (for example, for an input.txt file with 3 lines in total, the final message is: "Total instances of @ characters at output.txt:  3")

so yeah thats pretty much it lmao i guess im using the atCount thingy wrong?? any help could be appreciated <3

Comment: ```(s.equals(" "))``` -> You are checking if the whole line is equal to a whitespace. You must find the whitespaces inside ```s```

Comment: @OlivierDepriester thanks for your comment, i tried writing `fw.write(s.replace(" ", "@"));` and then: `for(int i=0; i<s.length();i++){if(s.charAt(i) == '@') atCount++; }` but it still doesnt work it says there are 0 @!!

Answer (score 0):

Your approach finding the whitespace was not correct here is the solution, instead of searching in the whole string and count each line, you have to check each character and count it

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String s  = "the unstoppable marching of time\n" +
                "that is slowly guiding us all towards\n" +
                "an inevitable death";
        int countSpace = 0;
        if (s.contains(" ")) {
            for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
                if (s.charAt(i) == ' ') {
                    countSpace++;
                }
            }
            s = s.replace(' ', '@');
        }
        System.out.println(s);
        System.out.println(countSpace);

    }
```

Comment: ok this is epic i tried something simmilar and it worked fine!! thank u 